# org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id

Tags: mysql, solr4

While indexing a MySQL database table with Apache Solr, I received the following error:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id
```

What does this mean?  How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This means that Solr is trying to index a document which doesn't have a field id specified. In your schema.xml you have defined an uniqueKey field, every document indexed by Solr needs such an id to be indexed.

Comment: Thanks for yours help!

I used two field in entity, 
(1) user_id-primary key (2) destination - FULLTEXT index.

Below i list my code for your reference.
data-config.xml:
<document name="emp">
<entity name="emp_rec" query="select user_id, destination from emp_rec">
<field column="user_id" name="user_id"/>
<field column="destination" name="destination"/>
</entity>
</document>

schema.xml:
<field name="user_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="destination" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false"/>

Any idea what I am missing? Thank you!

Comment: You need to look in your schema.xml file. In there you will find a declaration of the primary key called uniqueKey. You need to change the value in this tag to user_id. A second option is to change the name of user_id to id in your data-config file.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.Denis!

Indexing process of apache solr with mysql database was completed successfully and it works in the solr Admin area.

But i could not search any text in my drupal site, it returns the error message "Search is temporarily unavailable. If the problem persists, please contact the site administrator." Even after configured in apache solr search form in the site admin panel ("admin\config\search\apachesolr").

Is need to do any additional configuration in our drupal site to implement solr search? why this would happen? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error message is very general. Does the Solr server report any errors? I have no experience in combining Solr with Drupal, so I'm afraid I can't help you with the configuration of Solr in Drupal.

Comment: Yes it returns the following error in solr admin: "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field hash" for the above error i added the following code in schema.xml, "<field name="hash" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>" and then later i received the new error as like below, "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field access__all". Its okay no problem, Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

One of the reason must be In Solr there should not be id field as int. It should always be string. I got same problem because I defined id field as integer instead of string.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same error. My table name was voter and i used voterid as as a unique id . But after I changed the column name voterid as id it worked for me.
This is my data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"
            user="root"
            password="root" /> 
  <document name="voter">
    <entity name="voter" query="select *  from voter;" >
 <field column="id" name="id"/>    
   <field column="voter_name" name="voter_name"/> 
<field column="age" name="age"/>   
</entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>


Schema.xml File(I added 2 field , id was already present in the file)
```

`<field name="voter_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

`<field name="age" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

`<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`